# Angular / Ionic - What problems can happen due to code exposure?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm developing an Angular / Ionic application. Taking a look at the files from the "build" folder, I could notice the code is reasonably readable and not minified, for example:

```
CartService.prototype.total = function () {
    var cart = this.getCart();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.items.length; i++) {
        sum += cart.items[i].produto.preco * cart.items[i].quantidade;
    }
    return sum;
};
CartService = __decorate([
    Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["Injectable"])(),
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__storage_service__["a" /* StorageService */]])
], CartService);
return CartService;
```

Is it a problem? What problems can happen due to code exposure?

Comment: Anyway, you must accept that ALL your front-end code is public, and therefore, all security must be handled by your server. Never trust anything that comes from the browser, and never send anything sensitive to the browser.

Comment: Do you use WebPack with UglifyJsPlugin? There are [other suggested plugins](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification) for minifying code with WebPack. But I see in [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/954) that there can be a problem for production builds of Angular/Ionic apps.

Comment: Dear @ConnorsFan never tried those, but thank you very much for advices. I'll consider that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find a lot of material on the topic if you search around, but there's 2 big things to consider when deciding whether to minify code or not:

1. **People stealing your code.** If your application is a core business asset, and anyone posessing your code in maintainable form can immediately become competition without working for it, this could threaten your company.
2. **More people exploiting security bugs.** Readable code lowers the expertise required to find exploits by a considerable margin. An experienced hacker can reverse-engineer minified code and will know lots of common attack vectors, of course, but any decent developer can find holes in readable code.

There's a 3rd reason, not as critical as the above for many applications, but still important:

3. **Performance**: minified code is smaller. It will transfer faster over the network. Some preprocessors capable of minifying also perform minor optimizations that can improve runtime, though these usually not noticeable.

If none of this bother you, and you'd like people to actually be able to read your code and see how you do things, you can keep it like that.